# log4net throws exception when configured to use non-default locking

Tags: c#, log4net

I hope this is not considered off topic, but it is a C# .Net problem of sorts:

I am using log4net 1.2.10. It has been stated on the apache log4net forum that from 1.2.9 onwards, different file locking schemas are available. I have configured log4net as per examples given to use a non-default method (minimal-locking or interprocess locking) but the immediate effect is the following error message:

log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Cannot find Property [lockingModel] to set object on [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.DefaultLoggerFactory+LoggerImpl]
log4net:ERROR [RollingFileAppender] Unable to acquire lock on file C:\Program Files (x86)\Autoscribe\Matrix Gemini LIMS\Exe\log\Trace.log. The process cannot access the file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Autoscribe\Matrix Gemini LIMS\Exe\log\Trace.log' because it is being used by another process.

My log4net.config file is:

```
    <logger name="Matrix.Trace">
         <!--this is for routine debug logging to a file--> 
        <level value="OFF" />
             <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender+InterProcessLock" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppenderTRACE" />
    </logger>

    <appender name="RollingFileAppenderTRACE" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value=".\log\Trace.log" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%m%newline" />
        </layout>
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
    </appender>
```

etc...

My C# application does this:

```
    private static readonly ILog bllDebugLog = LogManager.GetLogger("Matrix.Trace"); //for debugging
```

and

```
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new System.IO.FileInfo("log4net.config"));
```

If I use the default locking method, logging does work (but I have file-lock problems with multiple processes, which is what I am trying to resolve).

I cannot see from the log4net documentation why this should fail. The error appears to suggest that log4net 1.2.10 does not support non-default locking, but the apache documentation is quite clear that it should. What am I doing wrong?

TIA

Comment: I've now upgraded to log4net 1.2.13 (.net 3.5 build), and I get a different error message: "log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Cannot find Property [lockingModel] to set object on [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.DefaultLoggerFactory+LoggerImpl]". If I look at the log4net dll in VS object browser, the FileAppender class clearly has that property available, so what's up here?

Answer (score 2):

Apologies all round - I was being dumb. The lockingmodel bit needs to go in the appender definitions, not the logger definitions, and it appears the locking model should be log4net.Appender.FileAppender+InterProcessLock, not log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender+InterProcessLock (even though I am using a RollingFileAppender logger type).